# Запятая перед будто

Tags: пунктуация, сравнение

Помогите, пожалуйста. Нужна ли здесь запятая перед будто? "Похоже, жители деревни почитали его будто древнего бога".
"Будто" здесь в значении "словно", а не в значении "в качестве".

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: **Комментарии были [перемещены в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147832/discussion-on-question-by-----); пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь.** Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с [назначением комментариев](/help/privileges/comment). Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть [ответами](/help/how-to-answer), размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1.  Краткая теория сравнительных оборотов**

В общем случае нельзя приравнять сравнительный оборот к определенному члену предложения, так как у него более сложное строение. Но в трехчастных конструкциях с двойными связями (два предмета сравниваются через действие) могут проявляться в большей мере: (1) **обстоятельственные отношения**  (почитали как?); (2) **сравнительные отношения** (он, как бог; его, как бога).

**При обособлении** мы подчеркиваем сравнительное  значение, а **при отсутствии обособления** — обстоятельственное значение, причем в какой-то мере это зависит **от позиции** оборота в предложении. Так, сравнительный оборот в конце предложения не обособляется  чаще, чем в других позициях. В то же время в общем случае обособление сравнительных оборотов является более частотным вариантом.

Таким образом, сравнительный оборот (даже при отсутствии в нем значения «в качестве») может быть **обособлен или не обособлен**. Это зависит от структуры и семантики предложения.

**2. Анализ предложения**

Структура заданного предложения допускает **оба варианта**, при этом они хорошо различаются на слух.

**Вариант 1.** Обособление. *Похоже, жители деревни **почитАли** его, будто древнего **бОга**.*

При обособлении ударение падает на глагол и на оборот. В первой части говорится, что жители почитали его (основное содержание), а дальше следует сравнение.

**Вариант 2.** Нет обособления. *Похоже, жители деревни почитали его будто древнего **бОга**.*

При отсутствии обособления ударение падает только на оборот, который входит  в основное сообщение (почитали как бога).

**3. Вывод**

Здесь возможен **авторский выбор** написания и произношения, но для информационной  карточки, как я думаю, больше подходит **второй вариант**.

Можно еще отметить, что сравнительное значение оборота (даже при отсутствии обособления)  подчеркивает **союз «будто»**  (при  значении «в качестве» обычно используется союз «как»). Это важный момент.

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ**

Интересно значение глагола.

ПОЧИТАТЬ,  нсв. кого-что. Относиться к кому-, чему-л. **с уважением, почтением; чтить.** П. старших. П. предков. П. законы, традиции.

ПОЧЕСТЬ, св. кого-что, кем-чем, каким и за кого-что. Признать, **счесть кем-, чем-л.,** каким-л. (**с оттенком почтительности, вежливости**). П. себя счастливым.  <Почитать,  нсв.

Видно, как **сближаются** значения глаголов ***уважать*** кого-л. и ***считать*** кем-л. (с оттенком почтительности).

Поэтому в этой теме т**рудно различить** сравнение (почитать будто бога) и значение "в качестве" (считать богом, приравнивать к богу). Это характерно для современного языка, а раньше  почитать кем-то не имело обязательный оттенок уважительности, например: *И в то время, когда современники почитали его **лютым извергом**, царь был иного мнения*.

Comment: Это противоречит правилам. Докажите, что образ действия. Должен подходить творительный падеж или т.п. Хоть что-то должно быть. А здесь ничего. Не любой оборот может быть обстоятельством образа действия! Образа действия же, а не просто обстоятельство.

Comment: О чем вы? Вот предложение:  Древние славяне почитали его подземным богом, повелевающим морозами.  Почитали кого?  сильное управление. Почитали кем? Обычное управление Т.п. Почитали его как бога.  Сравнительный оборот в той же позиции в роли обстоятельства образа действия. А каким еще обстоятельством может быть сравнительный оборот? Значение непонятно? Так чтили, что считали богом, возводили в ранг божества.

Comment: Это не русский язык. Это какая-то жесть! Творительный не подходит!

Comment: Не подходит, не надо. Сравнительный оборот находится в позиции  обстоятельства, глагол не задает ему падеж.

Comment: *Почитали кем? Подземным богом.* Это неверное управление. Может, любое ставить в позицию обстоятельства и считать из-за этого обстоятельством? Вы любое считаете обстоятельством, это неверно. Это не зависит от позиции. От позиции зависит пунктуация, если оборот может быть обстоятельством. А вы тупо по позиции и ударениям определяете. Это неверно.

Comment: Уважаемый участник! Разговор с вами закончен. Критику оформляйте в поле ответа по правилам форума и чтобы не тупо было. До свидания.

Comment: По правилам она должна быть под ответом. Критиковать в ответах никто не разрешал. Они не должны зависеть друг от друга.

Comment: Вы просто неправильно понимаете, что такое обстоятельство образа действия. Это не просто оборот, на который падает ударение. Впрочем, мало кто правильно понимает.

Answer (score 1):

Запятая не нужна: оборот с *будто* входит в состав сказуемого.

**Похоже, жители деревни почитали его будто древнего бога**.

Comment: Почему входит? Когда входит, предложение без оборота некорректно.